# Extract certain area of contours/satellite images

Tags: qgis, merge, clip, imagery, extract-by-mask

I have 2 satellite images (jpeg2000 format) and 2 xyz-files from the same area. I am trying to extract certain region from the area including contour lines and the satellite image in order to import these into Google Sketchup for terrain modeling.

I have been able to create contour lines from xyz-files. Anyway, I would like to first merge contours and then satellite pictures and finally extract only certain part of the data (both contours and satellite pictures). Is there some kind of instruction available that would help in a problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of the question, you want to:

1) Overlay the contour lines you have already created onto the satellite imagery.

2) Clip out a section of the imagery.

If you are only concerned with a true-color image (RGB) and you don't need to actively change the bands (e.g. to create a false color composite) you might consider converting your vector features (contours) to raster and then adding these as a new band to your satellite imagery. You will then need to clip the imagery to your desired extent - for this you can simply create a new polygon feature and use it to clip your imagery.

Answer (score 1):

you can also clip the raster using the raster>clip menue then you can intersect the contours with a polygon